# Create an IAM role for an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying to create an IAM role for S3 bucket, I have to select a role type from a list of AWS services, but I can't find "Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)"  anywhere. any proposed solutions?
Here is a screenshot from the page involved.
[image: here is a screenshot from the page involved]

Comment: Are you trying to create a role that gives something access to an S3 bucket? Or are you trying to create a role that allows S3 to access other AWS resources?

Comment: already solved by selecting Cognito role manually, and change the policies in the JSON file.

Comment: @AlaDouagi you are misunderstanding the purpose of this screen.  This is used when you want the selected service to access other services on your behalf, using assumed roles, and here you would select the service to be granted the privilege -- not the service being accessed.